# ManyToMany field to same model without allowing the same object

Tags: django, django-models

I am using Django with a model that has a ManyToMany field to the same model.

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(_('Name'),max_length=80, blank=True, default="")
    related_jobs   = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

this works fine. I can create Job objects and add jobs to related_jobs.
The problem is that I can associate the same object to himself like this:

```
job1 = Job.objects.create(name='Java')
job2 = Job.objects.create(name='Python')
job1.related_jobs.add(job2)
job1.related_jobs.add(job1) #I don't want this to be possible
```

Is there anyway to restrict this on the models?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a composite key, in Django this is done using the [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint). Although, in your case to apply this constraint I believe you are going to need a [intermediate table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).